# How do I turn on HTTP caching in Yii2?

Tags: php, http-headers, yii2

I set these values in the controller, yet it's not working.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'httpCache' => [
          'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
          'sessionCacheLimiter' => 'public',
          'cacheControlHeader' => 'public, max-age=3600',
        ],
    ];
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-http.html#cache-control

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:81/xxxx/web/shopping/search?q=toaster
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2015 08:58:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.12
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=t07qapiiv7crdkva14ojn6cvg5; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: search=4ef489ad7fa4567884eebc22279836f85acec05395053c863ed86c2679be9477a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A38%3A%22%2Fxxxx%2Fweb%2Fshopping%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtoaster%22%3B%7D; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: _csrf=72e0104d312d81ddde455cff7566d3d186e3b25f8f41fc03a1f4a533d9b739ada%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22R1HklhizymwcXPVxJkBCvNR2gBwInqdw%22%3B%7D; path=/; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Since there were no answers to the question, I just updated the question. I found a cause for Yii not outputting all the headers, but I still don't know how to turn caching on. In fact, now it is actively turning caching off with `Cache-Control: no-cache`, even though I requested it to be on.

Even with a test action, it sets `no-cache`.

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:81/xxxx/web/shopping/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=bvdnd33uu8qj0s88q2sr7n7696; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
[...]
```

`php.ini`

```
$ grep cache_limiter  /etc/php5/php.ini
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```

I discovered that calling `session_cache_limiter` manually got it to output `Cache-Control`, but not the value that I set. This is probably a bug because `sessionCacheLimiter` specifically says that's what it's for.

```
public function behaviors() {
    session_cache_limiter('public');
```

Gives

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
```

And it still sets cookies when no session is used. This prevents caching for the CDN we are using.

Yii version 2.0.6.

Comment: how about doing it at the Apache level?

Comment: I have separate caching for other pages. Some pages, like the admin section, should not have caching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `\yii\filters\HttpCache` you should set at least [`lastModified`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-httpcache.html#$lastModified-detail) or [`etagSeed`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-httpcache.html#$etagSeed-detail) :

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
    'lastModified' => function ($action, $params) {
        return time();
    },
    'sessionCacheLimiter' => 'public',
    //'cacheControlHeader' => 'public, max-age=3600', // not needed since it is the default value
],
```

Take a look here : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.6/framework/filters/HttpCache.php#L111

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even need `sessionCacheLimiter`, `session_cache_limiter()`, nor `cacheControlHeader` then! I wish the docs said that it was required. I suppose I assumed it would use the current time as default. I could have sworn I tried `lastModified`, but that was probably when I was using `flush()`, which breaks the headers. Now I have to find out how to stop setting session cookies.